# Make child text of rotated SVG element upright

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG element which gets applied a `transform: rotate(0deg)` value which moves a circle around something else. I'd like to add text to the center of the circle, but the problem I'm running into is that because the circle and text share the same rotate property for alignment the text is unreadable because it is often times upside down.

Is there a way to make the text that sits within the circle always be upright without manually changing the `circle` and `circle-text` css properties? Is there some sort of way I can make the `tspan` element orient its self back to whatever the browser default is?

```css
svg {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

circle {
 transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.circle-text {
 transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.container {
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <svg width="200" height="100">
  <circle cx="64.5" cy="0" r="10" fill="#472e12" />
   <text class="circle-text" x="64.5" y="0" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff">
     <tspan>-30</tspan>
   </text>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution: I'm putting both the circle and the text inside a group: `.theg`, and I'm rotating the group `50deg`. Next I'm rotating the text `-50deg` and also I'm setting `transform-origin:64.5px 0;` i.e. the text is rotating around the center of the circle.

Also I've added `dominant-baseline="middle"` to the circle. I hope this is what you need.

```css
svg {
 width: 100%;
}
.theg{
 transform: rotate(50deg);
}
.circle-text {
 transform-origin:64.5px 0;
 transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <g class="theg">
  <circle cx="64.5" cy="0" r="10" fill="#472e12" />
   <text class="circle-text" x="64.5" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="#ff0">
     <tspan>-30</tspan>
   </text>
   </g>
 </svg>
</div>
```